# Python Pandas; "excel" column operations

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, calculated-columns

I am quite new to python. Searching previous questions I couldn't find the answer to this problem.

For a project I have to analyze a lot of .txt files and always perform the same calculations on it. To create a dataframe pandas was used, which works nicely.

I want an extra column with calculations performed on other columns, so for example c = a + b.
For simple calculations this works just fine:

```
In [41]: import pandas as pd
In [42]: import numpy as np

In [43]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),columns=list('ab'))

In [44]: df
Out[45]: 
      a         b
0  0.163138 -1.261099
1  0.094772 -0.553349
2 -1.677519 -0.966680
3  1.732083 -1.118715
4  0.172240 -0.404648
5  0.270712  0.089841
6  0.589787  1.569790
7  0.822016  0.857993
8 -0.269941  0.586059
9 -0.152639  0.240438

In [46]: df["c"] = df["a"] + df["b"]

In [47]: df
Out[48]: 
      a         b         c
0  0.163138 -1.261099 -1.097961
1  0.094772 -0.553349 -0.458577
2 -1.677519 -0.966680 -2.644198
3  1.732083 -1.118715  0.613368
4  0.172240 -0.404648 -0.232407
5  0.270712  0.089841  0.360554
6  0.589787  1.569790  2.159576
7  0.822016  0.857993  1.680010
8 -0.269941  0.586059  0.316118
9 -0.152639  0.240438  0.087800
```

The problem encountered happened when using more "complex" calculations:

```
# C1 and C2 are some constants needed for the calculations

In [49]: C1 = 1.5

In [50]: C2 = 2.5

In [51]: df["c"] = df["a"] + [(C1 * df["a"]) + (C2 * df["b"] ** 2)]

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Is there a workaround to this problem? Or am I handling this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the error is that you're wrapping the inner calculation result in square brackets, removing this fixes the error:

```
In [157]:

df["c"] = df["a"] + (C1 * df["a"]) + (C2 * df["b"] ** 2)
df
Out[157]:
          a         b         c
0  0.163138 -1.261099  4.383772
1  0.094772 -0.553349  1.002418
2 -1.677519 -0.966680 -1.857622
3  1.732083 -1.118715  7.459016
4  0.172240 -0.404648  0.839950
5  0.270712  0.089841  0.696959
6  0.589787  1.569790  7.635069
7  0.822016  0.857993  3.895420
8 -0.269941  0.586059  0.183810
9 -0.152639  0.240438 -0.237071
```

The issue is that the inner calculation produces a list containing a Series:

```
In [159]:
[(C1 * df["a"]) + (C2 * df["b"] ** 2)]
​
Out[159]:
[0    4.220634
 1    0.907646
 2   -0.180103
 3    5.726933
 4    0.667710
 5    0.426247
 6    7.045282
 7    3.073404
 8    0.453751
 9   -0.084432
 dtype: float64]
```

You then try to add the other column/Series and it doesn't understand how to align

Comment: Thanks, removing the brackets worked fine! And indeed, I just wanted to multiply the result of df["b"] ** 2 by the constant C2, so that part was already ok.

Comment: OK wasn't sure, will remove the last part